# Change row with each use

Tags: excel, row, vba

So I have this chunk of code, that when run will ask for a set of data, which will then be added to a table, and trigger some other actions. What I desperately need however, is for this macro to run a new row each time it is used, rather than overwrite the same row.

Anyway, would really appreciate some assistance

```
Sub TestMacro()

    Range("B" & "12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Name")
    Range("c" & "12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Northing")
    Range("d" & "12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Easting")
    Range("e" & "12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Transition Length (Ls)")
    Range("f" & "12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Minimum Radius (Rc)")
    Range("g" & "12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Central Angle (DELTA)")
    Range("u" & "13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("B160")
    Range("v" & "13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("C160")
    Range("w" & "13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("D160")
    Range("x" & "13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("E160")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What may work for you is to use an event on a worksheet and a UserForm:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        UserForm1.Show
        MsgBox UserForm1.TextBox1 ' do stuff with form objects
        Set UserForm1 = Nothing ' skip this step to retain form values between calls
    End Sub
```

Create a UserForm to capture the data then process the data on return from the form.

In this case the form pops up every time you change cells in the sheet so that may not be the best solution. You can put the same code in a SUB() and add a shortcut key:

```
    Sub GetData()
        UserForm1.Show
        MsgBox UserForm1.TextBox1 ' do stuff with form objects
        Set UserForm1 = Nothing ' skip this step to retain form values between calls
    End Sub
```

Open the Macros dialog on the Developer tab (you may need to turn on the tab in Options) then set the SHortCut key via the Options... for the GetData macro.

You can preload some of the objects on the UserForm:

```
    Sub GetData()
        UserForm1.TextBox1 = "Hello"
        UserForm1.Show
        MsgBox UserForm1.TextBox1 ' do stuff with form objects
        Set UserForm1 = Nothing ' skip this step to retain form values between calls
    End Sub
```